# Как решить проблему с masonry?

Tags: jquery, плагин

Есть лента новостей, вытаскивается из vk.com. 
С помощью [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) выстраиваются новости, как кирпичики.
Если контент внутри новости занимает более 500px появляется кнопка "раскрыть". При клике на кнопку "раскрыть" новость открывается полностью. При повторном клике - закрывается.

Есть кнопка "загрузить еще". При клике, с помощью Ajax, достается 5 новостей. Но уже не работает кнопка "раскрыть" в первых 5 новостях. А в тех которые загрузились - все работает.
Естественно после получения новостей я все перезапускаю

Дальше хуже.
Если жмем еще раз на кнопку "загрузить еще" появляются еще 5 новостей. В этой 5ке и в первой 5ке все работает , но не работает уже в предыдущей 5ке.

Выкладываю ссылку, что у меня получилось [goo.gl/a3KlLg](http://goo.gl/a3KlLg)

Я в замешательстве...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//запуск masonry
$('.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
  $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: '.gut',
    percentPosition: true
  });
  // если высота больше 500, то удалить кнопку "раскрыть"
  $(".grid-item div").each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() < 500){
    $(this).children(".expan").remove();
    }
  });
});

// функция раскрыть/скрыть 
$(".grid-item .expan").click(function(){
  $(".grid .grid-item").css({"maxHeight": "500px"});
  $(".grid-item .expan").text("раскрыть");

  if ($(this).parent().parent().attr("class") == 'grid-item inn'){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('inn').css({"maxHeight": "500px"});
  }
  else {
    $('.grid-item').removeClass('inn');
    $(this).text("скрыть");
    $hei = $(this).parent().height();
    $hei += 50;
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('inn').css({"maxHeight": $hei + "px", "height": $hei + "px"});
  }
  $('.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
    $('.grid').masonry();
  });
});

$("#imgLoad").hide();  // Скрываем прелоадер
var num = 6; //чтобы знать с какой записи вытаскивать данные

$(function() {
  $("#load .button").click(function(){
  $(".button").next("#imgLoad").show();

  $.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"num": num},
    cache: false,           
    success: function(response){

        if (response == 0){ // Смотрим ответ от сервера и выполняем соответствующее действие
          $("#imgLoad").hide();
        }
        else {
          var $elems = $( response );
          //добавляем элементы masonry с помощью appended
          $('.grid').append( $elems ).masonry( 'appended', $elems ).imagesLoaded(function() {
            $('.grid').masonry({
              itemSelector: '.grid-item',
              columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
              gutter: '.gut',
              percentPosition: true
            });
            // если высота больше 500, то удалить кнопку "раскрыть"
            $(".grid-item div").each(function(){
              if ($(this).height() < 500){
                $(this).children(".expan").remove();
              }
            });
          }); 
          num = num + 5;
          $("#imgLoad").hide();

          // функция раскрыть/скрыть 
          $(".grid-item .expan").click(function(){
            $(".grid .grid-item").css({"maxHeight": "500px"});
            $(".grid-item .expan").text("раскрыть");

            if ($(this).parent().parent().attr("class") == 'grid-item inn'){
              $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('inn').css({"maxHeight": "500px"});
            }
            else {
              $('.grid-item').removeClass('inn');
              $(this).text("скрыть");
              $hei = $(this).parent().height();
              $hei += 50;
              $(this).parent().parent().addClass('inn').css({"maxHeight": $hei + "px", "height": $hei + "px"});
            }
            $('.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
              $('.grid').masonry();
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
});
```

Comment: Вы поменяйте лучше `$(".grid-item .expan").click(function()` на чтото подобно к : `$('body').on('click', '.grid-item .expan', function()` тогда функция будет работать со всеми элементами которые будут загружены с помощью *ajax*, а то дублирование когда в *ajax success* не ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы поменяйте лучше `$(".grid-item .expan").click(function()` на чтото подобно к : `$('body').on('click', '.grid-item .expan', function()` тогда функция будет работать со всеми элементами которые будут загружены с помощью ajax, или созданы другим динамическим способом.